# Huge CPU usage by "host" command on my web server (ubuntu, apache )

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Suddenly my website became very slow. When I login into my sever with ssh, and checked the cpu utilization, I found host command was utilizing more than 80% cpu. The problem was solved by a server restart. But I am afraid it can be come back. Any explanation of the possible cause?

Comment: You might want to scan your filesystem for files named "host", to be sure there's only the one (something like `find / -name host 2>&1` should do the trick)

Comment: This is the output of your command :

/usr/bin/host
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-40/drivers/memstick/host
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-40/drivers/usb/host
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-40/drivers/mmc/host
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-40-virtual/include/config/scsi/sas/host
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-40-virtual/include/config/bcma/host

Comment: Looks reasonable... I can't imagine why it would be doing that. Probably something you'll have to keep an eye on, especially since you don't know how it got started.

Comment: I am getting abuse report from amazon , my server is on Amazon EC2 , hackers are using my server to attack on other websites , is host command high usage due to that ?

Comment: Did they say what kind of attack?

Comment: this problem is solved by uninstalling sendmail . Somehow hacker got access to my sendmail and using this sending spam to other site

Comment: A better find command is: `sudo find / -executable -type f -name host 2>&1`. In my case, it just returned one result, `/usr/bin/host`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/bin/host executed by hacked PHP script](http://serverfault.com/questions/705217/usr-bin-host-executed-by-hacked-php-script)